# Change multiple views background color

Tags: android, background-color

I have a lot of views using one and the same color as a background. I want to change the color of all views when I receive a call from the server programmatically. I don't want to call for every view

```
view.setBackgroundColor(new color);
```

Is there a way to change a color code that is in colors.xml.

Comment: changing color wont help, because `VIEWS` are already drawn on screen, you have to `invalidate` and `validate` your views in order to reflect change and that will give you a flick

Comment: If all Views are positioned next to each other you could also make their backgrounds transparent and change the window's or parent element's background color...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't. The resources are defined at compile time.

See this question for a similar case: [How can I programmatically change the value of a color in colors.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281182/how-can-i-programmatically-change-the-value-of-a-color-in-colors-xml)

Answer (score 2):

You can't replace the value of the color in the xml file. **But** you 
can create different *themes* which are used in your application and
change the theme dynamically

See this tutorial:

http://www.developer.com/ws/android/changing-your-android-apps-theme-dynamically.html

Comment: Yes, but I do not have the colors predefined, I receive the color on the fly. May be if there is a way to change a theme color programmatically, but it is in xml again ....

Answer (score 0):

What I end up doing is create a custom class that sets the color form preference. And use this class everywhere I want to change the color. And next time the view is drawn it gets the new color. Something like this:

```
public class ColoredToolbar extends android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar {

public ColoredToolbar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setBackgroundColor(context);
}

public ColoredToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setBackgroundColor(context);
}

public ColoredToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setBackgroundColor(context);
}

private void setBackgroundColor(Context context) {
    int color = PreferenceHelper.getToolBarColor(context, Preferences.PREF_TITLE_BAR_COLOR_KEY);
    this.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

}